# How to update Drupal custom module after changing .install file

Tags: database, hooks, drush

I am working on a pre-created Drupal 8 project that has a custom module called CCA(named out of project title). I have done the below update in the .install file to add a new column to the backend via Drupal.

```
function cca_update_8902 (&$sandbox) {
  db_add_field('cca_findings', 'cca_topic_id', array(
    'type' => 'float',
    'not null' => FALSE,
    'description' => 'interim fields addition',
  ));
```

How do I update the module in Drupal after this change has been made? Can someone guide on next steps to update my custom module in Drupal so that this change will be implemented? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visit `/update.php` on your site when logged in as admin, or use `drush updatedb`

Note that in addition to changing the table in the `hook_update_N()`, you must also change the schema of the `cca_findings` table in `hook_schema()` so that new installs of your module will have the proper table structure. Update functions are not used on new installs of your module.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any example of changing hook_schema() please?

Comment: The table is already defined in hook_schema(), right? It would have to be if this is a custom table for your custom module. If you look at the existing schema then it should be obvious how to define the new column - something like:
  `'cca_topic_id' => array(
    'type' => 'float',
    'not null' => FALSE,
    'description' => 'interim fields addition',
  );`

Comment: Yeah, the table is already defined in the schema. I am just adding additional column to it. In that case can I just skip this step?

Comment: Thanks! The accepted solutin worked perfecttly for me.